# css hack for vertical scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

if i make a div element have overflow:scrollbars i get both scroll bars vertical and horizontal all I want is the vertical scrollbars how do i accomplish that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

> overflow-y : visible
>
> overflow-x : hidden

. All the available options are listed [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `overflow` use `overflow-y` in css.

> **overflow-y: String**
>
> Specifies how to handle content
>   overflow of an  element if the content
>   is too tall for the element.
>
> Supported: IE 6.0+

But might not support some browsers so its better if you design your div so that elements do not exceed the x limit.

Comment: Actually it is supported in all the modern browsers and also IE >= 6. Use it safely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your aswer

use `overflow-y`

jscroll pane is very nice plugin for these kind of stuff

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Comment: `overlow-y` is only available in CSS3.

Comment: Yes but some browsers seem to respect that.